# Azure Function on a Service Bus Queue in .NET Isolation doesn't work for multiple messages

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues

Recently I need to upgrade my Azure function from `WebJobs.ServiceBus` to `Azure.Function.SDK`.

I need to upgrade this because I was getting the application configuration version issue.

After upgrading to Azure Function Service Bus SDK, my function is no longer working and I get this error:

> Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.FunctionInputConverterException: Error converting 1 input parameters for Function 'Function1': Cannot convert input parameter 'myQueueItem' to type 'System.String[]' from type 'System.String'.

Would anyone please look into it and help me solving this problem?

Thank you for your time

Rushi

My code - `MyFunction.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>    
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.AppConfiguration.AspNetCore" Version="6.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus" Version="5.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Dynamics.Sdk.Messages" Version="0.5.17" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration" Version="6.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.19.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.14.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.15.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

My `Program.cs` file:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace CFX.Alerts.SBProcessor
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
                    var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<Function1>>();
                    services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger), logger);
                })
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

My `function.cs` file:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace CFX.Alerts.SBProcessor
{
    public class Function1
    {
        [Function("Function1")]
        public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("customer.dev", Connection = "AzureWebJobsServiceBus")] 
        string[] myQueueItem, ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vup8j.png)

I tried various ways, removing and ensure to have the latest packages.

I followed these articles:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `IsBatched` on your trigger.
Also, if you're planning on using `ServiceBusMessageActions` you'll need to receive messages as `ServiceBusReceivedMessage[]`.

```
[Function(nameof(ServiceBusReceivedMessageBatchFunction))]
public void ServiceBusReceivedMessageBatchFunction(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("queue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection", IsBatched = true)] ServiceBusReceivedMessage[] messages)
{
    foreach (ServiceBusReceivedMessage message in messages)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Message ID: {id}", message.MessageId);
        _logger.LogInformation("Message Body: {body}", message.Body);
        _logger.LogInformation("Message Content-Type: {contentType}", message.ContentType);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Sean, that IsBatched was missing and after that, it started working. I followed the Microsoft link and nowhere did it mention that parameter.  About your comments on ServiceBusMessageActions, I tried that too earlier but had no luck, so was just trying the simplified implementation. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome, @RushikeshJoshi.